# Can mysqlimport accept JSON input?

Tags: json, mysqlimport

We currently have certain logs composed of pipe-delimited text, which has the format

```
field1:value1|field2:value2|...|fieldN:valueN\n
field1:value1|field2:value2|...|fieldN:valueN\n
etc.
```

I have an importer script (bash that runs perl and then mysqlimport), which currently removes a few words from the beginning of each row and then runs mysqlimport on the resulting text file.

We are upgrading our logging to a data service that outputs JSON. The importer script will still be importing the content of that JSON into a MySQL database table. It feels like bad form to take that nice JSON and convert it into a pipe-delimited file for use with mysqlimport - but do I have any options? I couldn't find anything in the mysql documentation or forums.

Comment: It turns out that there is good logging output from mysqlimport, which our scripts use downstream to provide status emails. I am loath to touch more pieces of this process than I have to, while I am adding in the JSON. I'm actually parsing the JSON to a pipe-delimited file for use with mysqlimport after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather convert the solid JSON to equally solid, a mysqldump compatible [SQL multiline `insert` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within parentheses and separated by commas. Example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
> ```

Since you're using a Perl script anyway, this shouldn't pose much of a problem.

Comment: This is one of those where I feel incredibly stupid that I didn't think of this myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Just a friendly criticism:** For me, it is bad to convert a:

- json text string -> to pipe-delimited data -> to pipe delimited parser -> to database or
- json text string -> to pipe-delimited data -> to pipe delimited parser -> to array -> to database.

Pipe delimited has lesser support than a json string.

The best way to do it is to maintain the data in a json string.

Then, you can parse it with any programming language you are comfortable with. Put it in an array for instance. Then, save each array in a database accordingly.

**But**, if this is what your company is using, and they already have a pipe-delimited parser,  if they already are building one, or it is hard for you to suggest that (whatever the case of impossible ways of convincing them). Then, the best way is to just stick with it for a moment.

If you have time on your own, you can be able to build your own

- json parser -> to array -> to database application.
- json parser -> to database application. (based on key and value)

It's easier.